# C++ How To Make Function Crash Upon Being Called Twice (32bit Machine)

Tags: c++

A program can be re-injected & functions that should only be called once are called twice because the program was re-injected. One way to help prevent this would be to have some of these functions that should only be called once crash upon being called a second time.

I came up with this with no luck:

```
void exmapleFunction(int r3, int r4)
{
    //Where our normal function code would go
}

exmapleFunction(1, 0);//our first call
*(int*)(&exmapleFunction) = 0x00000000;//set first instruction of our subroutine to 0 to hopefully cause a crash if the function is attempted to be called again
```

Though this did not cause a crash if I tried to call the function a second time which confused me.

And if you are wondering, this is just one of many techniques I'm implementing into my software to **help** make it more annoying to a person attempting to crack my software. Though, please ignore that and just focus on the matter of the question.

Comment: Do you have control over the function definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void exampleFunction(int, r3, int r4) { 
    static bool crash;

    if (crash) 
        *(int *)NULL = 1;

    crash = true;
    // do something useful here
}
```

Of course, this won't do much to accomplish your real goal, but it will normally crash on a second or subsequent execution nonetheless.

Comment: Why invoke UB when you could just abort?

Comment: @PasserBy: Because he specifically asked for it to "crash", not just abort (though I'll agree that aborting might well be preferable).

Comment: hm, will the same thing work for class' methods? Like I want different instances to not influence each other, but at the same time if one object calls the function twice I want to know about it.

Comment: @MichałSłodki: That sounds like it would require a rather different approach. This doesn't really differentiate between different callers.